# Trying to export Android App, but project is exporting as just a file? not an apk

Tags: android, eclipse, file, export, apk

I copied an application in order to make a "pro" version, with no ads. When i export it, it comes out as only a file? Not a .apk file as usual. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse, in the package explorer, right click on your package.

Click Android Tools >> Export Signed Application Package, and follow the prompts.
Is this what you are doing?

Comment: I think i will use this technique from now on, because just exporting the project is obviously giving problems more than once. Thank You for the help

Answer (score 2):

Ammmmmm maybe you're missing the "apk" extension on the export file name?

Try putting it a ".zip" suffix, unzip it, and see if its contents are the same as usual apk files...

Comment: I did this but then when i tried to extract an apk file, i had no luck because i dont have WinZip or any other compression software other than what came with my desktop. Thank You for the help

Comment: @Vicente  True, but Eclipse is already telling you that it is exporting the APK.  Why give .apk extension?  You don't do that in MS Word, do you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AVD emulator and you started at least once successful your app on AVD after your last modification of the source, you can find the *.apk file into bin directory of your project.

You can also read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: It was in the bin directory. But why is that? it exported just a file? and put the generated apk in the bin folder? Could you help me understand why?

Comment: As well as I cant upload the apk file that i found in my bin directory because it was signed with a debug cedrtificate

Comment: When you run your app on the AVD emulator, eclipse IDE automatically create apk archive (into bin directory) to install it on the Android Virtual Devise(AVD). This did not happen when you create/export it (the apk file) by yourself. If want to create it explicitly read the link, that I provided you about Signing Your Applications.